# Bulk Create Sequlize with where condition

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to update multiple rows arrived from array of objects.
currently my code working but it seems to slowly.

my cyrrent code :

```
async function updateData(array){
               for(const item of array){
                    await myCustomUpdateOrCreate(item)
}}

async function myCustomUpdateOrCreate(item){
               const foundItem = await myModel.findOne({where: {item.item_code,},});
               if(!foundItem){
                  await myModel.create({...item})
               }else{
                  await myModel.update({...item},
                 where:{
                       item.item_code,
                       item.otherProperty:someCondition 
                       }
}
}
```

This is too much times i connect to Db and perform changes (ofc in original code it with transactions and try&catch) .

I want use bulk create but unfortently there are 2 main issue that prevent it from me.

1. im not able to use where condition , im not willing to create or update each item in my array unless it pass my conditons as described above.
2. updateOnDuplicate allways return me error :

```
"there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"
```

(ofc my table contain unique so i cant understand that error)

Comment: Did you try `upsert`? And make sure you you all unique indexes as indicated in a model

Comment: @Anatoly - Yes , i tried. in my model the fields are unique but when i check in UI (debeaver) theres no unque constrains (why?)...anyway i updated unique constrain by querry interface to same column but it didnt solve nothing

Comment: Hwo do you sync models and DB structure?

Comment: @Anatoly : await model.bulkCreate(arr,options) where model is seeded to db earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem. Are you using docker image for postgres? If so try to drop the table and rebuild your container(I actually remove all volumes for DB) so then unique constraint will apply to your field in Model.

Check my answer here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085267/bulk-create-sequelize-option-updateonduplicate-throws-error-no-unique-matching-t/74085441#74085441[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085267/bulk-create-sequelize-option-updateonduplicate-throws-error-no-unique-matching-t/74085441#74085441%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085267/bulk-create-sequelize-option-updateonduplicate-throws-error-no-unique-matching-t/74085441#74085441)