# Bulk Create Sequelize option updateOnDuplicate throws error no unique matching the ON CONFLICT

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to create or update multiple rows if they already exist. Data arrived from array of objects.
I tried bulkCreate method with option 'updateOnDuplicate' but it returned me this error:

"[Nest] 23130  - 10/16/2022, 9:54:53 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Generated SQL from log:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "daily_price_change" ("date","id","fact_average_cost","plan_average_cost","city_id","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('2022-09-01',DEFAULT,'137838.44','0',1,'2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00','2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00'),('2022-09-02',DEFAULT,'137839.22','0',1,'2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00','2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00'),('2022-09-03',DEFAULT,'137840.89','0',1,'2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00','2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00'),('2022-09-04',DEFAULT,'137843.31','0',1,'2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00','2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00'),('2022-09-05',DEFAULT,'137843.27','0',1,'2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00','2022-10-16 07:15:15.457 +00:00') ON CONFLICT ("date") DO UPDATE SET "fact_average_cost"=EXCLUDED."fact_average_cost" RETURNING "date","id","fact_average_cost","plan_average_cost","city_id","createdAt","updatedAt"

In my model I have an unique field 'date':

```
@Table({ tableName: 'daily_price_change' })
export class DailyPriceChangeEntity extends Model {
  @Unique
  @Column({ type: DataType.DATEONLY, allowNull: false })
  date: string; // 2022-10-31

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.FLOAT, allowNull: true, defaultValue: 0 })
  fact_average_cost: number; // 105500.5

  @Column({ type: DataType.FLOAT, allowNull: true, defaultValue: 0 })
  plan_average_cost: number; // 105500.5

  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: true })
  city_id: number;
}
```

this how I connect Sequelize:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      models: [
        Model1,
        DailyPriceChangeEntity,
        Model2
        Model3,
        Model4,
      ],
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
...
```

If I remove unique constraint from my model then method will work but it will be create multiple records with the same data.

Please help, how I can perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!!

I set up my DB through the docker-compose so as far as I understood if you change some parameters into your Model you must drop the current DB and rebuild the container, so then those changes will apply. And now I have unique constraint in date field and it's type shows correctly